# Python: no hace lo que espero que haga

Tags: python, poo

estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python, estoy usando como guía "Aprenda a pensar como un programador en Python 2x", y uso Python 3.6.

Estoy en la parte de POO clases, métodos, atributos, etc; en la que usa como ejemplo un Juego de Cartas(la mona), el juego consiste en un mazo de 52 cartas, se elimina la reina de tréboles del mazo, se reparten las cartas a los jugadores de una en una; cuando se reparten todas las cartas, cada jugador debe eliminar las cartas con el mismo color y número de su mano(por ejemplo el 7 de trébol con el 7 de pica, el rey de diamante con el rey de corazón, y así) antes de empezar a jugar.

El problema está en `class ManoDeLaMona(Mano):`, cuando llamo al método `eliminaCoincidencias()`, este método se fija en la mano del jugador
e imprime las cartas que coinciden y las elimina de la mano, pero no lo hace, cuando llamo al método solo me devuelve 0, cuando saco el `print` del `if` toma las cartas de la mano y el mazo, imprime y elimina la coincidencias, pero no debería hacer eso.

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, y desde ya gracias.

```
import random


class Carta:
    listaDePalos = ["Tréboles", "Diamantes", "Corazones", "Picas"]  # esto es un atributo de clase
    listaDeValores = ["nada", "As", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Sota", "Reina", "Rey"]

    def __init__(self, palo=0, valor=0):
        self.palo = palo  # esto es un atributo de objeto
        self.valor = valor

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.listaDeValores[self.valor] + " de " + self.listaDePalos[self.palo])

    def __cmp__(self, otro):
        # controlar el palo
        if self.palo > otro.palo: return 1
        if self.palo < otro.palo: return -1
        # si son del mismo palo, controlar el valor
        if self.valor > otro.valor: return 1
        if self.valor < otro.valor: return -1
        # los valores son iguales, es un empate
        return 0


class Mazo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cartas = []
        for palo in range(4):
            for valor in range(1, 14):
                self.cartas.append(Carta(palo, valor))

    def muestraMazo(self):  # podemos reemplazar este método por un método __str__ que es más flexible
        for carta in self.cartas:
            print(carta)

    def __str__(self):
        s = ""
        for i in range(len(self.cartas)):
            s = s + " " * i + str(self.cartas[i]) + "\n"
        return s

    def mezclar(self):
        import random
        nCartas = len(self.cartas)
        for i in range(nCartas):
            j = random.randrange(i, nCartas)
            self.cartas[i], self.cartas[j] = \
                self.cartas[j], self.cartas[i]

    def eliminaCarta(self, carta):
        if carta in self.cartas:
            self.cartas.remove(carta)
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    def darCarta(self):
        return self.cartas.pop()

    def estaVacio(self):  # devuelve verdadero si el mazo no contiene ningún naipe
        return (len(self.cartas) == 0)

    def repartir(self, manos, nCartas=999):
        nManos = len(manos)
        for i in range(nCartas):
            if self.estaVacio(): break  # fin se se acaban las cartas
            carta = self.darCarta()  # da al carta superior
            mano = manos[i % nManos]  # a quién le toca?
            mano.agregaCarta(carta)  # agrega la carta a la mano


class Mano(Mazo):

    def __init__(self, nombre=""):
        self.cartas = []
        self.nombre = nombre

    def agregaCarta(self, carta):
        self.cartas.append(carta)

    def __str__(self):
        s = "La mano de " + self.nombre
        if self.estaVacio():
            s = s + " está vacía \n"
        else:
            s = s + " contiene\n"
        return s + Mazo.__str__(
            self)  # a un método de la claseMadre se puede pasar como argumento o parámetro una instancia(objeto) de una claseHija(subclase)


class JuegoDeCartas:

    def __init__(self):
        self.mazo = Mazo()
        self.mazo.mezclar()


class ManoDeLaMona(Mano):

    def eliminaCoincidencias(self):
        cant = 0
        cartasOriginales = self.cartas[:]
        for carta in cartasOriginales:
            empareja = Carta(3 - carta.palo, carta.valor)
            if empareja in self.cartas:
                self.cartas.remove(carta)
                self.cartas.remove(empareja)
                print(("Mano %s: %s con %s") % (self.nombre, carta, empareja))
                cant = cant + 1
        return cant


juego = JuegoDeCartas()  # creo el mazo para el juego

mano = ManoDeLaMona("Casio")  # creo un jugador para probar el método eliminaCoincidencias()

juego.mazo.repartir([mano], 13)  # reparto al jugador 13 cartas

print(mano)  # imprime la mano del jugador

'''Run el módulo'''

mano.eliminaCoincidencias()  # llamo al método y me devuelve solo 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es un poco difícil de detectar, pero muy fácil de solucionar.

Primero algunos detalles relativos a la depuración. Usando Visual Studio Code es muy sencillo añadir *breakpoints* al código, y ejecutar paso a paso las funciones a la vez que en un panel a la izquierda ves los valores de las variables locales.

Para que los valores allí mostrados sean útiles, cada objeto debería definir su método `__repr__()`, que es el que el depurador usa para mostrar ese objeto. En tu caso, lo que has escrito en `__str__()` estaría mejor en `__repr__()` para que sea usado por el depurador. Además, cuando haces `str(objeto)`, si el objeto no implementa `__str__()`, Python usará `repr(objeto)`, que se resuelve llamando a `objeto.__repr__()`, con lo que matas dos pájaros de un tiro. Es decir, definiendo solo `__repr__()`, funcionará también para `str()`.

Tras cambiar tus `__str__()` por `__repr__()`, esta es una captura de pantalla de mi sesión de depuración, donde puedes ver a la izquierda qué fácil es examinar los valores de las variables.

[image: Depurador]

Fue ejecutando paso a paso esta función como encontré la fuente del problema. En la línea que está iluminada en la captura de pantalla:

```
if empareja in self.cartas:
```

Python debe determinar si la carta "Reina de Diamantes" está en la mano. En este caso podemos ver que no está pero *aún si estuviera* **la comparación dará False**, debido a que el objeto referenciado por `empareja` acaba de ser creado en la línea anterior, y por tanto ese objeto *no puede estar en la mano del jugador* (que contiene objetos creados cuando se creó el mazo).

La fuente del problema, claro está, es que python compara las referencias para saber si un objeto está o no dentro de una lista. Necesitamos que compare los valores en lugar de las referencias.

Esto lo haría Python sin problemas si tuviera forma de comparar los valores (por ejemplo, en tuplas, diccionarios y listas así lo hace), pero cuando se trata de objetos definidos por el usuario (como instancias de la clase `Carta`) python no sabe cuándo considerar si son o no iguales, por lo que se limita a comparar las referencias.

La solución consite en dotar a la clase `Carta` de un método `__eq__()` que indique cuándo una carta es igual (en valor, que no en referencia) a otra. Así:

```
class Carta:
   # ... resto igual que estaba ...

   def __eq__(self, otro):
       return self.palo == otro.palo and self.valor == otro.valor
```

Con este simple añadido ya todo funciona correctamente.

Comment: Gracias funciona, creo que entendí, lo que pasaba es que estaba comparando dos objetos  que tienen igual valor pero ID diferente(por así decirlo), y el método Carta.__eq__ (), sobre carga (o sobre escribe) al operador "==" que se llama cuando se compara un objeto en una lista. Y el método __repr__() muestra los parámetros de un objeto como una cadena, pej. si tengo p1=Punto(); p1.x=2;p1.y=3; si uso el __repr__ como método dentro de la clase al imprimir p1 saldrá (2,3), y si uso __str__ saldrá __main__.class at 0xe1111. Voy a empezar a usar VSC o alguno parecido. Gracias por la ayuda.